# New Xamarin.Forms Project Missing References

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have created a brand new Xamarin.Forms project, targeting iOS, in Visual Studio for macOS, and when I try to build I get the following errors, in AppDelegate.cs, about missing assembly references.

[image: Missing iOS References]

I have tried adding references, but I am presented with a blank window.

[image: Blank References Window]

I also tried updating all NuGet packages, since I found an SO answer which suggested this might resolve the issue, but I'm still having the same problems.

This is my first experience of trying to use Xamarin, and so I really have no idea what I'm supposed to do or what references the project requires to be able to build.

The following are all the dependencies the template project starts out with.

[image: Template dependencies]

Does anybody know what it is that's missing? How can I get this working? I have XCode 9.3 installed, and Visual Studio is up to date, so that shouldn't be an issue I don't think.

The following image shows the structure of the two projects created when I ran the wizard to generate the new Xamarin.Forms solution.

[image: Both NetStd and iOS project trees]

Comment: Under **References**, you should have a reference to `Xamarin.iOS`. What you are showing appears to be a NetStd project, not the iOS project as it would be a be a "normal" .Net framework project that has a framework target of `Xamarin.iOS`. It would be really strange for a template driven Form's solution/projects creation process not to have a Xamarin.iOS reference within the iOS platform target project unless you are manually creating them.

Comment: @SushiHangover My project is called TodoQ. When I created the Xamarin.Forms project, it created two projects. TodoQ, the Xamarin.Forms project, and TodoQ.iOS which is the Xamarin.iOS Project. However, TodoQ, the Forms project, has an AppDelegate.cs file which is referencing the same Xamarin.iOS code. However, there is no way to add the necessary references.

Comment: The Forms project (PCL|NetStd) should not have a `AppDelegate.cs`, that should be in the Xamarin.iOS project

Comment: @SushiHangover I have added a screenshot showing the two projects that were generated.

Comment: That solution is fubar (there are about 7 files under the Forms project that should be under the iOS project... :-/ Try recreating it from scratch.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks, I think I know what happened. I've deleted the project entirely and recreated from scratch and it's fine now.

Comment: Glad you got it working 